# Add a common ylab to patchwork plots in r

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I can *create* a `common_ylab`  for the `plots` produced by `patchwork::wrap_plots()`.

But I wonder how to *add* that `common_ylab`  to those `plots` (tried: `plots + common_ylab`)?

**Note:** Suppose we only have access to the `plots` object and can't manipulate the individual `p` objects.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(grid)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")


(plots = wrap_plots(p1,p2,p3,p4))

# Common ylab:
(common_ylab = grid::grid.draw(grid::textGrob("VS", x = 0.02, rot = 90)))

# Tried the following without success:
plots + common_ylab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tend to add a dummy ggplot here:

```r
p5 <- ggplot() + geom_text(aes(1, 1, label = "vs"), angle = -90) + theme_void()

(plots | p5) + plot_layout(widths = c(12, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Allan, thank you! I should have mentioned this, but I only have access to the `plots` object and can't manipulate the individual `p` objects.

Comment: `p5 + plots + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 12))`

Answer (score 0):

With [patchwork 1.2.0](https://www.data-imaginist.com/posts/2024-01-05-patchwork-1-2-0/), you can now use a new argument `axes = "collect_y"` inside `plot_layout`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+ylab("")


wrap_plots(p1, p2, p3, p4) +
  plot_layout(axes = "collect_y") &
  ylab("VS")
```

[image: Result of the code]