# Add a common xlab to patchwork plots in r

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot

I'm following up on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190276/7223434). In short, assuming we only have access to the `plots` object and can't manipulate the individual `p` objects, how can we add a common `xlab="mpg"` to the `plots` object?

**Note:** It would be great to add the `xlab` to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190276/7223434).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")


(plots = wrap_plots(p1,p2,p3,p4))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option could be by using `plot_annotation` and create a `title` and adjust the position of this title to your x lab position like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")

(plots = wrap_plots(p1,p2,p3,p4)) +
  plot_annotation(title = "xlab") &
  theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = -110, hjust = 0.50))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

This could also be done using the `caption` or `subtitle` instead.

---

**Edit:**

You could combine the x and y label like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs))+ geom_point()+xlab("")+ylab("")

(plots = wrap_plots(p1,p2,p3,p4)) +
 plot_annotation(title = "xlab",
                 subtitle = "ylab") &
 theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = -110, hjust = 0.50),
       plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = -55, hjust = -0.01, size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, but how do you add this `xlab` to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190276/7223434)?

Comment: Hi @rnorouzian, Please check my edited answer! You could create the xlab also using a annotation.

Comment: But ylab angle is incorrect, it must be turned 90 degrees clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since [patchwork 1.2.0](https://www.data-imaginist.com/posts/2024-01-05-patchwork-1-2-0/), you can use a new argument `axis_titles = "collect"` inside `plot_layout`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()

wrap_plots(p1, p2, p3, p4) +
  plot_layout(axis_titles = "collect")
```

[image: See the result]

If you want to have only a common x axis title, you can use `axis_titles = "collect_x"` instead.